# Refresh from Server Eclipse

Tags: force.com-ide

I updated a class in a sandbox via the developer console. I'm trying to update the code change in Eclipse by using "refresh from server". However, the code is not updating in Eclipse even though it shows completed. Could you let me know what I'm doing wrong?   Thanks

Comment: Do you have the file listed in package.xml?

Comment: This is what I have in the package. DuplicateLead is the class.                   
         <types>
        <members>DuplicateLead</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>

Comment: Have you tried refreshing `src/classes` and see if the contents are updated?

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the wrong package. You're spot on. My package didn't have the correct metadata. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding details from comments.

> I was looking at the wrong package. You're spot on. My package didn't have the correct metadata.

To be able to refresh a component from server to a local workspace, you need to make sure that the component is listed in the `package.xml` file of the project.

Excerpt from [Refresh from Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_refresh_from_server.htm) topic from the documentation:

> **Refresh from Server** refreshes only the contents specified in the `package.xml` project manifest file. That is, if a file in your project is removed from `package.xml`, you no longer receive new versions of that file when performing a **Refresh from Server**.